# javascript continue refreshing page after api load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

I'm trying to send a request and get answer from my own synonyms api. The api works very well. And the javascript is getting the answer, but it keeps refreshing the page and in the end there's no output in my html. 
This is my html script:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="question" />
    <button class="gen-syn">Generate synonyms</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.gen-syn',function(){
 var questionVal = $(".question").val();
 if (questionVal == ''){
    $(".question").focus();
 }
 else {
   $.ajax({
       type :'POST',
       url : "http://192.168.1.9:5000/synonyme_word/"+questionVal,
       success : function(response){
           var divSynonymes = $(document.createElement('div'));
           $(".question").after(divSynonymes);
           for (var a in response){
               $(divSynonymes).append('<h1 class="titre-textareal-question-icona-go " value=>'+a+'</h1>'+
               '<div class="form-group row" >'+
                   '<div class="col-sm-12 listeSyn">'+
                   '</div>'+
               '</div>'
               );
               for (syn in response[a]){
                 var synonyme = response[a][syn]
                 $(".listeSyn").append(
                     '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[249]" id="frm-test-elm-110-100" autocomplete="off" />'+
                     '<div class="btn-group">'+
                         '<label for="frm-test-elm-110-100" class="btn btn-primary">'+
                             '<span class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg"></span>'+
                             '<span class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg"></span>'+
                             '<span class="content">'+synonyme+'</span>'+
                         '</label>'+
                     '</div>');
               }
           }
       },
    });
    return False;
 }
});
```

I didn't make any reload, but the navigator keeps reloading after calling the api (when I click on Generate synonyms button)

Comment: You can try to 'return false' when your js functions has finished

Comment: Clicking that button will also submit the form the regular way. Like Janneck says, `return false;` from an event handler in order to stop the event.

Comment: Get rid of the `<form>` altogether. Its behaviour messes with your code. Just use a `<div>`.

Comment: Sorry, I added `return False;` it worked at first but then returned to reloading the page. @Jeremy your suggestion worked very well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `<form>` altogether. Its behaviour messes with your code. Just use a `<div>`.

Comment: oh, I too added the answer..realize late.....anyways your suggestion is the answer here...

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue.

```
<input type="text" class="question" />
<button class="gen-syn">Generate synonyms</button>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

you need only one button to make a `API` call and then your `JS` code is creating dynamic `div` and other elements to show the synonyms.

Hope this helps.